# Rewriting jQuery's .on('mouseenter') into pure JS variant

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a container div containing other div elements:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

How can I rewrite the following jQuery in pure JS?

```
$('#container').on('mouseenter', 'div', myFunction)
```

That is, how can I listen which child mouse is hovering over in order to apply to it `myFunction`? I've tried the following, but this only applies `myFunction` to container div:

```js
container.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event) {
  let hoveredElement = event.target;
  if (hoveredElement.tagName === 'DIV') {
    myFunction(hoveredElement);
  }
});
```

```css
#container { width: 200px; }
#container > div  { height: 100px; background-color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I've also tried `event.currentTarget`, but it still gives the same results.

p.s. I do not want to put event listeners on children of the container div, because there is a great number of children.

*Edit:* I've removed `console.log(hoveredElement);` It was a line for debugging.

Comment: @KevinB You're right. It's not a copy paste mistake, it's a writing mistake. The div has an `id="container"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start at the `e.target`, and traverse up the ancestors, invoking the handler on each `div` that you find. You stop traversing the ancestors when you get to the bound element.

Also change the event type to `mouseover`, since `mouseenter` doesn't bubble, and so the `event.target` is always the bound element.

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#container");

container.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
  let el = event.target;
  do {
    if (el.tagName === 'DIV') {
      myFunction.call(el, event);
    }
  } while((el = el.parentNode) !== this);
});

function myFunction(event) {
  console.log(this.id);
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
  <section>
    <div id=foo>
      <p>Hover me to invoke the function</p>
    </div>
    <p>This one does not invoke</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Didn't notice that you had lowercase `"div"`, so I uppercased that too.

---

Note that you can abstract this out to a reusable function for convenience. You can also make it more generic by using a CSS selector and `.matches()` instead of being limited to tag name comparison.

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#container");

delegate("mouseenter", container, "div", myFunction);

function myFunction(event) {
  console.log(this.id);
}


// Reusable event delegation maker
function delegate(type, container, selector, handler) {
  if (type === "mouseenter") {
    type = "mouseover";
  } else if (type === "mouseleave") {
    type = "mouseout";
  }

  container.addEventListener(type, function(event) {
    let el = event.target;
    do {
      if (el.matches(selector)) {
        handler.call(el, event);
      }
    } while ((el = el.parentNode) !== this);
  });
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
  <section>
    <div id=foo>
      <p>Hover me to invoke the function</p>
    </div>
    <p>This one does not invoke</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: It works! But to be honest I do not understand how `this` within my function knows to refer to the child `div` without taking a reference to `this` as an input.

Comment: @Liliane: I invoked `myFunction` using `.call()`, which lets you manually set the value of `this`. So I passed `el` as the first argument to `.call()`, which sets it as `this` in `myFunction`, and passed `event` as the second argument to `.call()`, which passes it as the first argument in `myFunction`.

Comment: Thanks, I see now in the documentation. I do not need to pass the event then to `myFunction`, since I do not have any processing to do on the event itself, only on the child.

Comment: @Liliane: Up to you, but I'd pass it just to keep it consistent with how event handlers typically work, especially if you're going to use the generic `delegate` function in the second example.

Comment: Also, my initial solution works if I change `mouseenter` to `mouseover`. Then, there is no need for do/while, and `.call()`

Comment: @Liliane:  Yes, you do need the loop if you want to emulate jQuery's delegation on `mouseenter`. In your example, it'll work because there are no nested elements in the children, but in my example I intentionally made it a little more complex to add a nested element, which means the `e.target` is not actually the `div` you want, so it needs to traverse up.

Comment: ...and `.call()` is just for good, consistent handler behavior. If you don't want to use it, then just pass the element as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

I debugged jQuery on Chrome, and **the jQuery `mouseenter` event is actually using a `mouseover` event under the hood.**

In the jQuery source, line 4095, there's a line that's run every time an event is triggered:

`jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( elem, arguments );`

If you pause there and inspect `arguments`, you'll find that it's a MouseEvent with a type of `mouseover`.

Which sort of makes sense, since you're using jQuery's delegate event handler syntax, and jQuery is being clever enough to substitute `mouseenter` [which doesn't bubble and doesn't trigger as you move through the event handler's descendents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) with `mouseover` [which does fire when you move through the listener's children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover).

So, **your solution is essentially going to be doing what jQuery is doing--use `mouseover`:**

```js
container.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
  console.log("mouseover target", event.target);
  console.log("mouseover currentTarget", event.currentTarget);
});

container.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event) {
  console.log("mouseenter target", event.target);
  console.log("mouseenter currentTarget", event.currentTarget);
});

$('#container').on('mouseenter', '.child', function(event) {
  console.log('jquery mouseenter target', event.target);
  console.log('jquery mouseenter currentTarget', event.currentTarget);
  console.log('jquery mouseenter delegateTarget', event.delegateTarget);
});
```

```css
.child {
  border: 1px solid #007;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's confusing how target in mouseenter and mouseover are different. But logging to the console really helped.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is a practice called Event Delegation. It's pretty easy to do given the state of JavaScript today. To replicate JavaScript syntax you're used to I created a returnable object to use.

You use `$get( query )` to get the element you want to perform delegation on. From there you use the `on` method with the parameters `(event, query for child elements, function)`

When you're writing the function for the `on` method, it will be passed the `event` parameter, per usual, but the next parameter will be the index of the element that is, in this case, mouse overed.

There is no safe guard for the parameters because that's not part of the question and it's something that can easily be solved with a little elbow grease :)

```
let $get = (query) => {
  if (document.querySelector(query)) {
    let returnableObj = {
      ele: document.querySelector(query),
      list(q) {
        return Array.from(this.ele.querySelectorAll(q))
      },
      getIndex(ele) {
        return function(q) {
          let foundIndex;
          returnableObj.list(q).filter((itm, ind) => {
            let bool = ele.isSameNode(itm);
            if (bool) foundIndex = ind;
            return bool;
          });
          return foundIndex >= 0 ? foundIndex : false;
        }
      }
    }
    returnableObj.on = function(evt, childquery, fn) {
      this.ele.addEventListener(evt, function(e) {
        if (e.target.matches(childquery)) {
          let myIndex = returnableObj.getIndex(e.target)(childquery);
          fn(e, myIndex);
        }
      });
    }
    return returnableObj;
  } else alert('invalid query');
}
```

```js
let $get = (query) => {
  if (document.querySelector(query)) {
    let returnableObj = {
      ele: document.querySelector(query),
      list(q) {
        return Array.from(this.ele.querySelectorAll(q))
      },
      getIndex(ele) {
        return function(q) {
          let foundIndex;
          returnableObj.list(q).filter((itm, ind) => {
            let bool = ele.isSameNode(itm);
            if (bool) foundIndex = ind;
            return bool;
          });
          return foundIndex >= 0 ? foundIndex : false;
        }
      }
    }
    returnableObj.on = function(evt, childquery, fn) {
      this.ele.addEventListener(evt, function(e) {
        if (e.target.matches(childquery)) {
          let myIndex = returnableObj.getIndex(e.target)(childquery);
          fn(e, myIndex);
        }
      });
    }
    return returnableObj;
  } else alert('invalid query');
}



let ele = $get("#mydiv");
ele.on("mouseover", ".child", function(e, ind) {
  alert('Peanut Butter! Child ' + (ind+1));
})
```

```css
h1,h2,h3 {
width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <span>hiya</span>
  <h1 class="child"> child 1 want some candy?</h1>
  <h2 class="child"> child 2 I choose you, spirit dragon</h2>
  <h3 class="child"> child 3, Scoreboard  </h3>
</div>
```